# Alternative way to write IN clause in GQL

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gql

How to write below query in GQL

> select * from test WHERE lid=1234 AND status IN (1,7,8)  order by sent_datetime DESC

Exception while executing above query :`GQL query error: Encountered "IN" at line 1, column 46. Was expecting one of: "contains", "has", "is", "=", "<", "<=", ">", ">=", ".", "("`

And all the columns are indexed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IN` is a feature of some client libraries and isn't strictly part of the GQL language of the server. You can do the same thing that the client libraries do to emulate this feature by issuing a query for each value in the `IN` clause and dedup results.

So this:

```
select * from test WHERE lid=1234 AND status IN (1,7,8) order by sent_datetime DESC
```

Would become these:

```
select * from test WHERE lid=1234 AND status = 1 order by sent_datetime DESC
select * from test WHERE lid=1234 AND status = 7 order by sent_datetime DESC
select * from test WHERE lid=1234 AND status = 8 order by sent_datetime DESC
```